# What is the difference between combinator and supercombinator?

Tags: haskell

What is the difference between combinator and supercombinator? Both of them do not contain any free variables. That is the one thing, that I know.

Comment: Explanation and an example of a combinator that is not a supercombinator can be found here: https://wiki.haskell.org/Super_combinator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A supercombinator is either a constant, **or a combinator which contains only supercombinators as subexpressions**.

Or more completely,

> Any lambda expression is of the form \x1 x2 .. xn -> E, where E is not
>   a lambda abstraction and n≥0. (Note that if the expression is not a
>   lambda abstraction, n=0.) This is a supercombinator if and only if:
>
> - the only free variables in E are x1..xn, and
> - **every lambda abstraction in E is a supercombinator**.

A combinator does not contain any free variable, but might have a subexpression that does.
For example, from [Haskell Wiki: Super combinator](https://wiki.haskell.org/Super_combinator)

```
\f g -> f (\x -> g x 2)
```

the outer lambda function is indeed a combinator because it has no free variables, however its subexpression `\x -> g x 2` has a free variable (`g`), so it is not a combinator. It follows that `\f g -> f (\x -> g x 2)` cannot be a supercombinator

Comment: To be fair, that definition at the top is written in such a way that the only possible super combinator is a constant. For example, `\x -> x` cannot be a super combinator, because (1) it is not a constant, and (2) it contains a subexpression `x`, which is not a super combinator.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin The definition is from the Haskell Wiki and I only took the simple bit because I thought it was obvious what it meant, but I'll update it now